# Node, mongo and loop, how to break loop when I find data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My code looks similar to that:

```
var mongo_client = require('mongodb').MongoClient, dataStorage;
lib = {
    [...]
    find: function(res, param, callback) {
        var parentPath = param.path;

        while (parentPath !== '/') {
            collection.findOne({'paths' : parentPath}, {...}, function(err, data)) {
                if (data) {
                    dataStorage = data;
                    callback(data, res);
                }
            }
            if (dataStorage) {
                return;    
            }
            parentPath = lib.removeLastBlockOfPath(parentPath);
        }
        if (!dataStorage) {
             callback(someDefaultData, res);
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

What I want to do is to find some path stored in mongo, or if there is no match, try do find first matching parent path.

I can't set dataStorage value from findOne callback is it any way to do that? Eaven if I find path it always run thru all path blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node is asynchronous, so your code must be written accordingly. An option is to use the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, that has lots of tools to manage asynchronous flows.

For example, you could use the [whilst](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#whilst) function to manage your `while` loop:

```
find: function(res, param, callback) {
  var parentPath = param.path,
      dataStorage = null;

  async.whilst(
    function () { return parentPath !== '/'; },
    function (done) {
      collection.findOne({'paths' : parentPath}, {...}, function(err, data) {
        if (data) {
          dataStorage = data;
          return callback(data, res);
        }
        parentPath = lib.removeLastBlockOfPath(parentPath);
        done();
      });
    },
    function (error) {
      if (!dataStorage) return callback(someDefaultData, res);
    }
  );
}
```

Don't forget to install and require the `async` module:

```
var async = require('async');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685529/how-to-do-find-using-node-and-mongodb...need help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written as if it is "traditional synchronous" -- which its not.  You cannot check for dataStorage validity till results from findOne() come back -- so your checks need to be moved all the way into the inner "if (data)" statement.  This is not a mongodb issue, this is purely how nodejs works and the fact that everything is asynchronous and works on callbacks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685529/how-to-do-find-using-node-and-mongodb...need help